# Replace spaces with colons in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string which is in keys-value pair format and separated by space. I want to separated by comma instead of space.

I tried replace function but its also replacing my values spaces with comma.

```
val = 'name=Ajay age=21 company=abc PVT LTD empid=12345'
```

my desired output:

```
'name=Ajay,age=21,company=abc PVT LTD,empid=12345'
```

Comment: But how do you know that the output is `company=abc PVT LTD,empid=12345` and not, say, `company=abc PVT,LTD empid=12345` or `company=abc,PVT LTD empid=12345`?

Comment: @Kevin Presumably because `empid=` has that equals sign. But still, the original format is suboptimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just match the `<word>=` pattern then replace them instead:

```
import re    
val = 'name=Ajay age=21 company=abc PVT LTD empid=12345'

pattern = re.compile(r' \w+=')
pattern.sub(lambda match: match.group().replace(' ', ','), val)

# Output
# 'name=Ajay,age=21,company=abc PVT LTD,empid=12345'
```

[This](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#search-and-replace) should also be a good reference for how the `sub` works with the `lambda`

Comment: this I would say is the best solution and you would just set a second variable equal to the pattern.sub. val2 = pattern.sub~

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
\w+=[^=]+(?: |$)
```

Check it on Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/GgbqxB/1

Comment: This pattern does look like it would sucesfully match individual key-value pairs. But how should you use it to get a comma-delimited string? I don't think `re.sub` will work out-of-the-box, since it will match the final key-value pair too, and you don't want to add a trailing comma.